# How to create virtual cube in mondrian cube framework?

Tags: cube, mondrian

I have got two tables through which I need to generate a cube report, I need to displayy measures from columns of both the tables. I browsed through the documents on the website and learned that VirtualCube is the way to go if I am to accomplish this feat. However the document is not very clear and lacks a working example. Can anyone suggest or give link to a working example (a mondrian.xml file) which can give me some clarity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you visit developer`s site? http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Virtual_cubes

Comment: In the meantime, I have left the project and moved on. I don't even remember what was my question.